# What exactly is moment? Why does it correspond to a rotation?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, terminology, definition, torque, moment

Wikipedia says:

> [Moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)) is an expression involving the product of a distance and physical quantity.

I don't quite get it. Moment is a vector, the cross product of the distance vector and the vector of the physical quantity, and it is **linear**. Why is it defined to correspond to an **angular** quantity like:

The moment of force is torque, and it is the product of angular acceleration and the rotational inertia;

The moment of momentum is angular momentum, the product of angular velocity and rotational inertia.

**Edit number 1:** I understand the definition. But why does the moment vector have to be constrained lie on the axis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "moment" have a single meaning in physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/587912/)

Comment: Are you asking why the cross product in both cases produces an "angular" quantity?

Comment: maybe this will help  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi.html  rotationl-linear parallels

Comment: @NiharKarve Basically, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will ask one question: what about the moment of inertia?

I think understanding why such a way of defining moments is useful is much more important than investigating the definition of a moment itself.

If you have a solid example of a certain concept, it's much easier to extend that to a more general case and find a comprehensive reasoning. So I will take the moment of inertia as an example, as well as the moment of force (torque).

The moment of inertia is defined as: $$I = \int dm  \ r^2$$ where $r$ is the distance from the rotational axis and $dm$ is a mass infinitesimal or, mathematically, the integrating variable.

So, the first thing you may notice is that $I$ is a **scalar** quantity. The moment does not have to be a vector quantity. That's one thing. As the Wikipedia page states, the moment can be either vector or scalar, and we can call anything in the form $r^n\times appropriate \ physical \ quantity$. Perhaps you can think of $r$ as being the magnitude of the vector $\vec{r}$ so that we can see the identicality of the scalar moment and the vector moment.

I will now move onto your second question: what determines the direction of the moment vector, for example the torque (the moment of force)? As you can see from its formula $\vec{\tau}=\vec{r} \times \vec{F}$, the **operation** that relates the radius (moment arm) vector and the force vector is **cross product**. If the torque were to be defined as $\tau = \vec{r} \cdot \vec{F}$ using the dot product (which doesn't make any physical sense at all) then the torque would have been a scalar, not a vector. So **the fact that the torque vector is orthogonal to both the radius vector and the force vector precisely comes from the pure mathematical properties of the vector cross product operation**. There's nothing to do with the physics here, other than that we can think the direction of the torque vector as being the direction of the rotational axis.

I will finish by leaving another comment on how we determine the positive/negative directions of torque vectors, which is namely the right hand rule. The right hand rule is followed not because it is a mathematical truth, but because mathematicians and physicists all over the world just chose to set that as a standard convention.

Answer (score 0):

To Edit number 1 : Well, if our world is 2 dimensional (only x, y axis), moment need not be a vector. If you rotate counterclockwise(ccw), you can just assign a positive scalar number, and if clockwise(cw), you can assign a negative scalar number.

One good fact of the 3 dimensional rotation is we can always define a single axis of rotation (this might look like a trivial statement in any dimension, but actually it is not). Therefore, we can consistently use our 2 dimensional case example, by assigning CCW to vector positively aligned to that axis, and for CW negatively aligned.

It is just a way to describe the direction and size in a consistent way. If you need more detailed treatment, google 'pseudovector' or 'axial vector'.